# Incorrect display name for smart contracts numeric return types

Tags: smart-contract, polkadot-js

When I deploy an ERC20 on Polkadot JS Apps, i can see that the return type of `total_supply` is `u128`, however according to the contract metadata it should display `Balance`.
Noticed also for ERC1155 messages, for example `create`

Is this intentional or is it a bug?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are most-probably assuming that something with a `displayName` of `Balance` conveys more information than it does. It does not refer to a specific instance of a `Balance` type on-chain nor to a specific pallet that ties it into any display formatting. For Substrate there is no real "one-balance-rules-all" indicator.

In terms of the balances pallet itself, something that has `displayName: Balance` is provided as a type in the config to the pallet instance, i.e. where it is instantiated in the runtime. The following is done (which the metadata then converts into the actual primitive type as well as `displayName` as used in the pallet code) -

```rust
impl pallet_balances::Config for Runtime {
    ...
    type Balance = Balance;
  ...
}
```

Now bear in mind that the chain itself can have multiple instances of this pallet (chains are not required to have only a single `Balance` instance and indeed a growing number does not) and for each of these instances, even if they do point to the same primitive type in terms of storage size, the formatting would be different in terms of token and decimals.

In the same fashion, there are multiple pallets that also take a config param of `Balance`, but in their cases it is not something that reflects native tokens or can be formatted in that way. An example is `assets` which also gets configured with a `type Balance = ...` whith a subsequent `displayName: Balance` but the formatting there is purely driven by the on-chain metadata for a specific asset instance. So here a `Balance` displayName cannot be equated to a `Balance` displayName that is in-use anywhere else. [1]

In the runtime contracts instantiation, the mapping for `Balances` is done via the `type Currency = Balances` where `Balances` refers to a specific instance of the balance pallet, here no `type Balance = ...` is injected into the config.

Contracts, as to be deployed via a `.contract` file, are even more loosely defined, since there is no trait config information that gets supplied or that can be used to tie a displayName to any runtime pallet that is available on-chain. Here the `Balance` formatting is up to the user intent.

So there is nothing in the metadata for the contracts pallet, nor in the contract-as-deployed types itself, that ties `displayName: Balance` to a type in the runtime, aka a specific instance of a balances runtime pallet. The `Currency = Balances` is not in the metadata mapping to infer which `Balance` instance is used. Contracts are certainly not tied to a specific runtime. What can be deduced 100% is the size of the type since that is absolutely specified, not the meaning and/or formatting. [2]

So in the current iteration, by design, unless the UI itself applies display overrides, each generic formatter only displays the primitive - as mapped to by the metadata type, never on the inexact string-name. There is just not enough information to actually try and map any single type to a specific instance of a same-name-type elsewhere. The apps UI deals in absolutes - unless it known 100% that there is an is exact match, it doesn't attempt it.

[1] They could refer, despite having the same name, to different underlying primitives, or the same primitive with obviously different meanings

[2] Not sure what happens when you deploy a contract containing types mapping `Balance` as `u128` on a chain with a `Balance` as `u64`. (e.g. ERC* doesn't really reflect an actual movable balances-pallet-instance balance, so no reason not to work, just not sure if there is checks or not...)